# google charts disappears after drawing

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, google-visualization

I want to draw a google chart with data from an ajax request. The data is correct and the datatable is loaded bus disappears just after has been drawn. Looks like the page is reloaded. Here may Page:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="includes/jquery/Themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css" type="text/css"/>
 <script src="http://www.google.com/jsapi"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://www.gstatic.com/charts/loader.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery/jquery-2.1.4.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/moment.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="includes/jquery.comiseo.daterangepicker.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="Datum">
        <table><tr>
        <td><input id="e1" name="DatePicker"></td>
        <td><input id="go" name="go" type="image" src="./Images/MonoIcons/circleright32.png" title="Auswahl bestätigen und Suche starten" width="30" height="30" /></td>
        </tr></table>
    </form>
    <div id="table_div"></div>
</body>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
     $("#e1").daterangepicker({
        dateFormat: 'dd.mm.yy',
        applyButtonText: 'übernehmen',
        clearButtonText: 'zurücksetzen',
        cancelButtonText: 'abbrechen',
        initialText: 'Bitte Zeitraum auswählen...',
        datepickerOptions: {
            minDate: null,
            maxDate: 0,
            numberOfMonths: 2,
               dayNamesMin: [ "So", "Mo", "Di", "Mi", "Do", "Fr", "Sa" ],
               monthNames: [ "Januar", "Februar", "März", "April", "Mai", "Juni", "Juli", "August", "September", "Oktober", "November", "Dezember"],
            firstDay: 1,
            weekStart: 1,
               defaultDate: 0,
        },
            presetRanges: [{
                text: 'Heute',
                dateStart: function() { return moment() },
                dateEnd: function() { return moment() }
            }, {
                text: 'Gestern',
                dateStart: function() { return moment().subtract('days', 1) },
                dateEnd: function() { return moment().subtract('days', 1) }
        }, {
                text: 'Letzte 7 Tage',
                dateEnd: function() { return moment() },
                dateStart: function() { return moment().subtract('days', 6) }
        }, {
            text: 'Letzte Woche',
                dateStart: function() { return moment().subtract('weeks', 1).startOf('isoweek') },
            dateEnd: function() { return moment().subtract('weeks', 1).endOf('isoweek') }
        }, {
            text: 'Letztes Quartal',
                dateStart: function() { return moment().subtract('months', 3).startOf('month') },
            dateEnd: function() { return moment().subtract('months', 1).endOf('month') }
        }, {
            text: 'Letztes Halbjahr',
                dateStart: function() { return moment().subtract('months', 6).startOf('month') },
            dateEnd: function() { return moment().subtract('months', 1).endOf('month') }
        }],
     });
     $("#e1_cl").click(function() { $("#e1").daterangepicker("clearRange"); });
});
</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    google.charts.load('current', {
    callback: function () {
        $("#go").click(drawChart);
        function drawChart() {
            $.ajax({
                url: "Statistik_getData_DocBtr.php",
                type: "POST",
                data: 'q=' + $("#e1").val(),
                dataType:"json",
                async: false,
                success: function(jsondata) {
                    console.log(jsondata);
                    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable(jsondata);
                    var options_table = {
                        showRowNumber: false, 
                    };
                    var formatter = new google.visualization.NumberFormat({decimalSymbol: ",",groupingSymbol: ".",fractionDigits:0});
                    formatter.format(data,1);
                    formatter.format(data,2);
                    formatter.format(data,3);
                    formatter.format(data,4);
                    formatter.format(data,5);
                    formatter.format(data,6);
                    formatter.format(data,7);
                    formatter.format(data,8);
                    formatter.format(data,9);
                    formatter.format(data,10);
                    formatter.format(data,11);
                    formatter.format(data,12);
                    formatter.format(data,13);
                    formatter.format(data,14);
                    formatter.format(data,15);
                    formatter.format(data,16);
                    formatter.format(data,17);
                    formatter.format(data,18);
                    new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById('table_div')).draw(data, options_table);
                }
            });
        }
    },
    'packages':['table']});
</script>
</html>
```

Has anyone an idea what is wrong?

this is an example data in json:

```
{"cols": [{"id":"","label":"Betrieb","pattern":"","type":"string"},{"id":"","label":"AB01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"AD01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"AN01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"BA01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"BE01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"BP01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"EMAN","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"EMSP","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"GU01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"KS01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"LA01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"LM01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"LS01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"RE01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"RE02","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"ZA01","pattern":"","type":"number"},{"id":"","label":"∑","pattern":"","type":"number"}],"rows": [{"c":[{"v":"0"},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":4},{"v":17},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":3},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":30}]},{"c":[{"v":"1"},{"v":836},{"v":0},{"v":118},{"v":14},{"v":216},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":0},{"v":17},{"v":10},{"v":417},{"v":112},{"v":142},{"v":0},{"v":1883}]},{"c":[{"v":"2"},{"v":419},{"v":0},{"v":140},{"v":4},{"v":234},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":35},{"v":11},{"v":489},{"v":130},{"v":126},{"v":2},{"v":1592}]},{"c":[{"v":"3"},{"v":62},{"v":0},{"v":32},{"v":0},{"v":43},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":10},{"v":1},{"v":33},{"v":4},{"v":22},{"v":0},{"v":207}]},{"c":[{"v":"4"},{"v":58},{"v":1},{"v":34},{"v":0},{"v":37},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":6},{"v":0},{"v":42},{"v":5},{"v":29},{"v":0},{"v":212}]},{"c":[{"v":"5"},{"v":42},{"v":0},{"v":13},{"v":0},{"v":28},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":23},{"v":2},{"v":11},{"v":0},{"v":119}]},{"c":[{"v":"6"},{"v":246},{"v":0},{"v":103},{"v":0},{"v":29},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":97},{"v":8},{"v":22},{"v":0},{"v":505}]},{"c":[{"v":"7"},{"v":128},{"v":0},{"v":76},{"v":0},{"v":69},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":169},{"v":0},{"v":1},{"v":154},{"v":154},{"v":126},{"v":0},{"v":877}]},{"c":[{"v":"8"},{"v":0},{"v":2},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":2}]},{"c":[{"v":"9"},{"v":19},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":24},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":43}]},{"c":[{"v":"A"},{"v":39},{"v":0},{"v":57},{"v":0},{"v":34},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":0},{"v":18},{"v":0},{"v":35},{"v":4},{"v":28},{"v":0},{"v":215}]},{"c":[{"v":"∑"},{"v":1850},{"v":3},{"v":574},{"v":18},{"v":690},{"v":1},{"v":4},{"v":17},{"v":3},{"v":169},{"v":88},{"v":23},{"v":1317},{"v":420},{"v":506},{"v":2},{"v":5685}]}]}
```

Comment: the example json only has 18 columns, which would be column index 0-17, running the above snippet with example data produces an error here --> `formatter.format(data,18);` -- try removing that line...

Comment: Hello! I removed all the formatting lines but still have the same Problem. I see the table for one second and then it disappears. And also the values set in the form are gone. I found out that the page is reloaded after the data table is drawn. But I don't have any idea why.